# Issue while converting Bootstrap 3 code into 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-5

I got this [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KSJa.jpg) from github. It's a little old. Bootstrap 3 was used. I want to convert it to Bootstrap 5. And here's [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwcu9.jpg) after I put Bootstrap 5 CDN instead of Bootstrap 3 CDN. What's the issue? How to fix it? Here's [the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-silence-6osjvz?file=/index.html).

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The migration from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 5 is a huge change, since Bootstrap 3 has been around since 2013.

I do not think there is an easy way to convert Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 5, due to many major changes and additions.

However, I would suggest you to go through the migration guides for more enlightenment.

I have found a tool online to convert BS3 to BS4 however I don't think there's one to convert to 5.

BS3 to BS4 converter tool: https://www.prepbootstrap.com/converter

Official bootstrap documentation for migration:

[BS3 to BS4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration)

[BS4 to BS5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your cache on your browser.

Comment: Check it again! There was bootstrap 3 cdn. Now I updated it to b-5.

Comment: In css file replace:

.team-socials {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

Comment: Cool. It worked. What about member img frame?

Comment: I changed img max-width: .team-member .member-img img { max-width: 250px to **295px**; margin: 0 auto; }. Now everything's good. Just images became bigger.

Comment: It's better, but far away from perfect. Resize the browser any you will see it has still a lot of bugs.